# Are there keyboard shortcuts for emoji on a bluetooth keyboard for iOS?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I've recently started using a bluetooth keyboard with my iPad. I was wondering if there are any keyboard shortcuts for emoji ? Switching to the on screen keyboard is possible but forces me to take my fingers off the hardware keyboard and tap the screen which is a huge waste of time. On Mac the autocorrect replaces stuff "<3" with their emoji equivalent but iOS doesn't seem to do that.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a workaround using the "text replacement" feature. In Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Text replacement, you can add the emoji and assign them their equivalent text-based shortcuts, like in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Those replacement lists ought to sync between Mac & iOS over iCloud, so you can use the same on both.